# Hard drive array usage

Tags: hardware, rack-layout

I recently bought this EMC server rack, it's got a bunch of hard drive arrays which came with it. How do I use these? Seems a shame to throw them away. Are these just a sort of NAS that I could configure, if so, how? Can they be used as individual drives if I pull them? [image]

Comment: Storage arrays aren't really on topic in this forum. See http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *controller* to run these.  Simply look up the model of that chassis and read the documentation.

Comment: Can I pull the drives and use them for other things? Can't look physically, they won't arrive for a month, but if they're useless to me I'd chuck them and use the space for other stuff, shipping is expensive.

Comment: Yes, they are a commodity item and are a standard size.  See [Hard disk drive interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_interface) on Wikipedia.  That 'plug' pinout on the chassis is a certain type, probably SATA or SAS.  Server Fault guys would probably be able to help more.

Comment: yeah they're SAS 15k, don't really have a use for 57 of them though

Comment: Also note, EMC does use custom firmware and lock drives to their array. They may also contain a security signature that will be erased if used in any other system that you may not be able to restore. (All part of the "certified drive" BS.)